# jquery trigger function is not working no error nor correct result

Tags: javascript, jquery

hey guys i have the ff code,it gives alert msg  when i **manualy** do it.
bt i want to do it programatically using jquery as follows:
the html code:

```
 <input type="text" id="inpt" />
```

**js code:**

```
   $("#inpt").keypress(function(e) {  
      if (e.keyCode == '13') {  
         alert("enter key pressed");  
      }  
   });
```

//call the abv event handler

```
 r=$("#inpt");  
    r.focus();  
    e = $.Event('keypress');  
    e.which =13; // ENTER_KEY  
    $(r).trigger(e);
```

It doesnt show an alert message and there is no error message
pls help!

Comment: bt it is working when i manual hit enter being in the input fld

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
if (e.keyCode == '13') {
```

To:

```
if (e.which == '13') {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BqAkR/